# Jest ignore Cypress test

Tags: jestjs, cypress

I have a `create-react-app` app and used to use `jest` for testing but I'm slowly migrating to `cypress`.

The thing is, now when I run my `jest` tests, it includes my `cypress` tests and gives an error

```
ReferenceError: Cypress is not defined
```

How can I make it that my `jest` (naming convention `*.test.js`) test ignore my `cypress` test (which are usually called `*.spec.js`)?

Comment: FWIW, Cypress isn't a replacement for Jest. It's integration/e2e framework and it leaves the app with no unit test coverage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `jest/config.js` or wherever you have your jest config (could be package), add the following to replace the default regex to find tests from

```
"testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$"
```

to:

```
"testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test))\\.[jt]sx?$"
```

Answer (score 34):

You should use `testPathIgnorePatterns` in your jest config.

> An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths before executing the test. If the test path matches any of the patterns, it will be skipped.

According to [Jest config docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring)

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
   // Your normal jest config settings
   testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/cypress/"],
}
```

Comment: If you already have jest configuration in the package.json file then simply add the 
line:  `testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/cypress/"],` in that configuration